# VueI18n passing string in a custom table VueJS

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

I am using vue-good-table for rendering tables.

```
 <vue-good-table
    :columns="columns"
    :rows="items"
    :paginate="true"
    :lineNumbers="true">
  </vue-good-table>

columns: [
          {
            label: 'Date',
            field: 'date',
            type: 'String',
            filterable: true,
            placeholder: 'Date'
          }
]
```

Is there anyway I can use for example {{ $t("column.date") }} in the label parameter. Until now it only works while passing a string?

***Add more code:***

**main.js**
    const i18n = new VueI18n({
      locale: 'bg', // set locale
      fallbackLocale: 'bg',
      messages // set locale messages
    });

```
Vue.prototype.$locale = {
  change (lang) {
    i18n.locale = lang
  },
  current () {
    return i18n.locale
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
columns: [
          {
            label: this.$t("column.date"),
            field: 'date',
            type: 'String',
            filterable: true,
            placeholder: 'Date'
          }
]
```

Comment: The output is "column.date", it's not working like that. It's not showing the real message

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks I made a typo mistake, however the switching between languages is not working for this component. When i click on the english/bulgarian button it stays on the bulgarian(default option).

Comment: In fact, it does change the language. However everywhere it changes the language except for the table. Is there any workaround?